# How do i send a large text file from node to python as a child process

Tags: node.js

I want to send the text file I upload to my node.js app to python in order to do some machine learning and be able to use the pandas and NumPy libraries.
I never worked with child process before but I found a tutorial and i came up with the following code :

```
app.post("/upload-txt", uploads.single("txt"), (req, res) => {
  //convert csvfile to jsonArray

  //const fileName = req.file.originalname;
  let contents = readTextFile.readSync(req.file.path);
  var largeDataSet = [];
  // spawn new child process to call the python script
  const python = spawn("python", ["script4.py", contents]);
  // collect data from script
  python.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log("Pipe data from python script ...");
    largeDataSet.push(data);
  });
  // in close event we are sure that stream is from child process is closed
  python.on("close", (code) => {
    console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
    // send data to browser
    res.send(largeDataSet.join(""));
  });
});`
```

This works fine for a limited number of lines in the text file but as soon as the file gets even remotely larger it does not, how do i fix this ?

Comment: Where exactly does the problem occur?  What exactly do you observe?  What is `readTextFile.readSync()`?  Where does that come from?

Comment: Where'd you go?  Try to help, but you're not responding to questions.

Comment: Hey, @jfriend00 I apologize I just saw your question,  the problem I get is "ENAMETOOLONG" whenever there are multiple lines on the text file, `readTextFile.readSync()` is what I use to read the text file and return its content

Comment: My question is where does `readTextFile.readSync()` come from?  What library does it come from?  And, what line of code causes ENAMETOOLONG?

Comment: it comes from the library `var readTextFile = require("read-text-file");` and i have no idea what line of code that causes the ENAMETOOLONG error here is a sample of the error though `Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
    at spawn (child_process.js:553:9)` it only happens on text files with multiple lines

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass an entire text file on the command line.  At some point, you just surpass the limit of what the OS will accept for command line arguments.  Some basic debugging here would examine what exactly is the value of `contents` in the case where you get an error.

Comment: `contents` is the content of the text file can you elaborate on how I can surpass the limit of what the os will accept or if there is another more convenient way to send text files to python i can extract data from and use machine learning on...

Comment: Send your python program a filename on the command line and let it read the data itself.

Comment: but I the idea is the file would be sent through the node.js server, for example, the user will upload a text file that gets sent to a python script that applies the ml and extracts data from...

Comment: Yeah, well your code ALREADY has the data in a file, right?  That's what you're doing with `readTextFile.readSync()` is reading it from a file that was created from the upload.  So, just send that filename to your python program.

Comment: am confused that's exactly what i did here `  const python = spawn("python", ["script4.py", contents]);` do you mind showing me exactly what you mean in an anwser!

Comment: There, you passed `contents` which is what you read from the file.  I suggested you pass the filename itself, not the contents of the file.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your data is sometimes too long for the command line in whatever OS you're using.  So, instead of passing the data itself on the command line, you can pass the filename on the command line and then modify the python script to get the filename from the command line, read the data itself (which won't be limited by command line limitations) and then process that data.

```
app.post("/upload-txt", uploads.single("txt"), (req, res) => {
  //convert csvfile to jsonArray

  var largeDataSet = [];
  // spawn new child process to call the python script
  // pass the python script the uploaded file as an argument
  const python = spawn("python", ["script4.py", req.file.path]);

  // collect data from script
  python.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log("Pipe data from python script ...");
    largeDataSet.push(data);
  });

  // in close event we are sure that stream is from child process is closed
  python.on("close", (code) => {
    console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
    // send data to browser
    res.send(largeDataSet.join(""));
  });

  python.on("error", (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: How do I get the filename from the command line on python this is what using `matches = re.findall(regex, sys.argv[-1], re.DOTALL)` but it's not working i tried `sys.argv[1]` as well...

Comment: @Souhail - I don't really know Python very well, but if you start a program like `python script2.py somefilename.txt` then `somefilename.txt` should be in `sys.argv[1]`.  That will be the filename so you will have to then read the content from that file in your python program before processing the data.